# Easy to setup FTP server on Linux?

Tags: linux, ftp

I am using Red Hat Linux Enterprise 5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

Could anyone recommend a free and easy to setup/maintain FTP server for my platform? I only need basic features and it will be used by a couple of people only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have ProFTPD, pure-ftpd, and vsftpd available for installation on your system.  While there are other ftp servers out there, these are packaged for RedHat (and RedHat derivatives such as CentOS).  I'm not particularly familiar with any of them, but of the three vsftpd apears to have the best combination of documentation + ease of use.

These should all be available on your RH5 installation media, or online via "yum install ..." or whatever equivalent RH5 uses.

Comment: Which one of them do you recommend for a beginner?

Comment: None. Use SFTP.

Comment: SFTP you mean http://www.coreftp.com/server/ ?

Comment: No. I mean install (should already be installed) SSH and then use SFTP. Much more secure. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol

Comment: @George: No problem.

Comment: I still can't get my vsftp to work for anonymous, coreftp is better.

Comment: Problem with 'sftp' is that it can be overkill (key exchanging,etc) if such features are not desired, since its using SSH.

Answer (score 4):

The standard OpenSSH  daemon  has a built-in SFTP service if you enable it.  You dont need to run a FTP server on your machine.  The SSH daemon handles it by a built-in module.   By the way, on Windows the WinSSHD freeware program does this also.   Also, using Tunnelier to connect to it is good.

> http://openssh.com/features.html
>
> As of OpenSSH 2.5.0, complete SFTP
> support is included, using the sftp(1)
> command as a client. The
> sftp-server(8) subsystem automatically
> works in both SSH1 and SSH2 protocol.

Comment: Yep.  Thanks for the edit.  http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_scp_sftp.html

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are sitting on RHEL ..then take a look at vsftpd..easy to install and use. Although as mentioned earlier by others SFTp is gr8! but a bit harder to use for newbie.

Cheers Mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SFTPPlus Server](http://www.sftpplus.com) it comes as a self contained package and provides support for FTP/FTPS (implicit and explicit) / SFTP / SCP / HTTP / HTTPS servers.

Support is provided for RHEL 4, 5, 6, 7 ...

Beside plain text configuration files, it comes with a web based management tool. Installing and configuring it should be very easy and it does not require advance Linux sysadmin skills.

I am one of the developers of SFTPPlus